# Locally working. But when i use parcel index.html it's not

Tags: javascript, html, parceljs

I have a pricing page where I have a toggle to switch between annual and monthly. At the end, I am linking to a js file like this.

```
    <div class="top">
          <div class="toggle-btn">
            <span style="margin: 0.8em;">Annually</span>
            <label class="switch">
              <input type="checkbox" id="checbox" onclick="check()" ; />
              <span class="slider round"></span>
            </label>
            <span style="margin: 0.8em;">Monthly</span></div>
        </div>

<header><h2><em>Hobbyist</em></h2>
  <p class="pricing text1">$2 per month</p>  
  <p class="pricing text2">$1 per month billed yearly</p>
 </header>
  

   <script src="js/pricing.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

And pricing js looks like this

```
function check() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("checbox");
  var text1 = document.getElementsByClassName("text1");
  var text2 = document.getElementsByClassName("text2");
  for (var i = 0; i < text1.length; i++) {
    if (checkBox.checked == true) {
      text1[i].style.display = "block";
      text2[i].style.display = "none";
    } else if (checkBox.checked == false) {
      text1[i].style.display = "none";
      text2[i].style.display = "block";
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting an error in the console as a result the toggle is moving but not kicking in the required javascript function that makes the pricing move between $1 and $2 dollars. Can someone suggest me how to fix this? I'm quite new to programming.

Error

```
    Uncaught ReferenceError: check is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):74:74)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
Pricing.js

function check() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("checbox");
  var text1 = document.getElementsByClassName("text1");
  var text2 = document.getElementsByClassName("text2");
  for (var i = 0; i < text1.length; i++) {
    if (checkBox.checked == true) {
      text1[i].style.display = "block";
      text2[i].style.display = "none";
    } else if (checkBox.checked == false) {
      text1[i].style.display = "none";
      text2[i].style.display = "block";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="pricing.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>

<div class="top">
  <div class="toggle-btn">
    <span style="margin: 0.8em;">Annually</span>
    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checbox" onclick="check()" ; />
      <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
    <span style="margin: 0.8em;">Monthly</span></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your responding. Move script tag to the head tag. Is that the fix? Could you please let me know why is that an issue.

Comment: i have copied your code and run on my computer its working fine there is no error like this

Comment: So when toggle movies ....pricing changes from 1$ to 2$. But in my case, only toggle moves, the pricing doesn't change. It working for me locally as well....but when I use parcel ...its not

Comment: please can you share more code? where i can see class names like text1, text2 in html

Comment: I have added some more code. let me know if you need more info

Comment: for now when i checked on Monthly its displaying "$2 per month" and when i uncheck its displaying "$1 per month billed yearly"

Comment: so please explain what will be the result when i check and uncheck

Comment: Intially $1 will be displayed..on moving toggle( checking) $2 will be displayed

Comment: <body onload="check()"> use this if we need to display $1 initially

Comment: What about onClick change. Currently I am getting the error check is not defined as shared in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245241/discussion-between-newbie-developer-and-chetan-ghadiya).